# how do you determine if a type is a functor or not in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functor

I have a data type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I want to determine, and not just for this data type, but for others such as String, if these data types are law-abiding instances of functor (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html). The link indicates that you can prove a type is a functor if it has a function fmap, which, given any types a and b, lets you apply any function of type (a -> b) to turn an f a into an f b, preserving the structure of f. How would I test this for my Tree data type, or String data type?

Comment: You can proceed analytically, by showing that `Tree` can be defined in terms of more primitive functors. For example, `type TreeF t = Sum (Constant ()) (Product Identity (Product t t))`, and `type Tree = Fix TreeF` (and you can show that this `Tree` is isomorphic to your definition). Since `Constant ()`, `Identity`, and the sums and products of functors are all themselves functors, then so is `TreeF t` (as long as `t` is a functor). I'm not sure of the exact argument for claiming that the fixed point of `TreeF t` is a functor itself.

Comment: @chepner Doesn't your alias lose the `a` parameter?

Comment: @amalloy I think so; I tried to flesh my comment out as an answer, and caught myself using `t` as both a type and a functor in the original draft. Comments and corrections on the answer are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

### Short non-answer

Before you do any thinking yourself, try to let GHC write the instance for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Tree a = Leaf | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Functor)
```

This happens to work in this case, and then you're guaranteed to have a law-abiding instance!

Seriously, this **is** the way you should typically acquire `Functor` instances for your data types. But you should still know yourself when it makes sense!

### Actual Answer

> I want to determine, and not just for this data type, but for others such as `String`, if these data types are law-abiding instances of `Functor`

So, for a `Functor` instance, you first of all need a *parametric type*, i.e. a “container” that doesn't care what type you store in it. So, strictly speaking the functor shouldn't be a type at all but a *type constructor* or *type-level function*<sup>★</sup>. Practically speaking, you see that by checking if the data declaration has type variables: in case of `Tree` you immediately see it in your code

```
data Tree a = ... ✓
```

If you don't have the source code handy, you can ask GHCi for the *kind*:

```
Prelude> :set -XTypeInType -XNoStarIsType†
Prelude> :k Maybe
Maybe :: Type -> Type  ✓
Prelude> :k String
String :: Type         ✗
```

As you see, `String` does not even have a type parameter, so it can't possibly be a functor.<sup>‡</sup>

Next, you need to look how the type variable is *used* in the data structure. If there are multiple type parameters, all of the following applies to the last (rightmost) of them, e.g. in `data Either a b = ...` we'd be talking about the `b` parameter.

- If it's not used at all (i.e. if it's a *phantom* type argument) then you can trivially write a law-abiding `Functor` instance: just don't use the mapping-function either.

  ```
  data Tough a = Tough String

  instance Functor Tough where
    fmap _ (Tough s) = Tough s
  ```

  (However perhaps you shouldn't write a functor instance in this case, because phantom arguments are often meant to be constant unique tags.)
- If it's used directly as part of one of fields in a type constructor, then you can write a functor instance. The `fmap`-ped function should then be applied to all those values.

  ```
  data Maybe a = Nothing
               | Just a

  instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a) = Just $ f a
  ```
- If it's used somewhere deeper nested in the data structure, but all the nesting is in functors itself, then it's a functor. (This also holds up if it's the same functor you're just trying to define yourself, i.e. for recursive types!)

  ```
  data TwoLists a = TwoLists {listL :: [a], listR :: [a]}

  instance Functor TwoLists where
    fmap f (TwoLists ll lr) = TwoLists (fmap f ll) (fmap f lr)
  ```
- [Advanced, probably best if you ignore this for now] if the nesting consists of not normal (covariant) functors, but of an *even number of contravariant functors*, then your whole type is also a covariant functor.

---

<sup>★</sup><sub>Type constructors are actually a very specific sort of type-level function, in particular they're injective. Mathematically speaking, a functor doesn't need to map its objects injectively (in case of **Hask**, the objects are types), but in Haskell this is necessary for the type checker.</sub>

<sup>†</sup><sub>These syntactic extensions cause GHCi to show the kind of types as `Type`; historically it would show `*` instead and that's still the default in older GHC version, but now deprecated.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>However, `String` is actually a synonym for `[Char]` i.e. a list of characters, and list *is* a functor. So you *can* actually perform `fmap` over a string, but that doesn't mean your using the “string functor”: you're using the *list functor*, and even if you started with a string the result may not be a string (but e.g. a list of integers).</sub>

Comment: thanks @leftaroundabout . I really like the short non-answer method. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the logic behind the actual answer, but in an exam - it would be too long to perform. My question is, how can I perform the short non-answer method for data types that are already defined, such as String, Maybe, IO, Gen, etc.

Comment: That would be an _orphan instance_, which is usually a bad idea. Generally you can trust that, if it makes sense for a type to have a `Functor` instance, then it _does_ have one defined right in its own module. If not, then there's probably a good reason. That said, there's always [`-XStandaloneDeriving`](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Stand-alone_deriving_declarations). — In an exam... better make sure that this is actually an accepted answer! If I phrased a question about how to implement `Functor` somewhere, I'd not give full marks for `deriving (Functor)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write such a function. If you succeed, it is definitely a Functor. If you fail, it might not be, or maybe you are not creative enough<sup>1</sup>. For Tree, it is relatively straightforward to implement, though of course a beginner may need to ask for help.

Specializing the signature of `fmap` to your Tree, you want a function with this signature:

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree f Leaf = _
mapTree f (Branch value left right) = _
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually there are many types that you can prove are not Functors just by looking at the fields of their constructors, but since that doesn't apply to Tree we won't get into it.

Comment: stiill not sure how to complete this function. I mean, what is the objective?

Comment: The objective is given in your question. "a function fmap, which, given any types a and b, lets you apply any function of type (a -> b) to turn an f a into an f b, preserving the structure of f." With f = Tree, you're looking for a function that preserves the tree structure, but modifies the elements contained in it.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is incomplete; I'm hoping someone can fill the hole I left regarding the functoriality of fixed points. Fact 5 and my use of it feel shaky.

---

`String` is not a functor, because it has the wrong kind. `String :: Type`, but a functor has to have kind `Type -> Type`.

Before we talk about `Tree`, let's establish a few facts.

1. `Constant a` (for any type `a`) is a functor:

   ```
   -- From Data.Functor.Constant
   newtype Constant a b = Constant { getConstant :: a }
   instance Functor (Constant a) where
       fmap _ (Constant x) = Constant x
   ```
2. `Identity` is a functor

   ```
   -- Adapted from Data.Functor.Identity
   newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }
   instance Functor Identity where
       fmap f (Identity x) = Identity (f x)
   ```
3. Sum types are functors, if the components are functors.

   ```
   -- From Data.Functor.Sum
   data Sum f g a = InL (f a) | InR (g a)
   instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Sum f g) where
       fmap f (InL x) = InL (fmap f x)
       fmap f (InR y) = InR (fmap f y)
   ```
4. Product types are functors, if the components are functors

   ```
   -- From Data.Functor.Product
   data Product f g a = Pair (f a) (g a)
   instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Product f g) where
       fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (fmap f x) (fmap f y)
   ```
5. Certain fixed points are functors.

   ```
   -- From Data.Functor.Fixedpoint
   newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

   instance (Functor f, Functor t) => Functor (Fix (f t)) where
       fmap g (Fix h) = Fix (fmap g (unfix h))
   ```

With these facts in mind, we will decompose our `Tree` type into a combination of sums and products of known functors, which will thus establish that our type is isomorphic to a functor, and therefore a functor itself.

First, `Leaf` is just a descriptive alias for `()`, and we can replace the recursive reference to `Tree a` with another type parameter.

```
-- This is slightly different from some explanations of
-- recursive types, where t would be the subtree type itself, not
-- a type constructor.
data TreeF t a = () | Branch a (t a) (t a)
```

Next, we get rid of `a` by noticing that the type `()` is isomorphic to `Constant () a` and `a` is isomorphic to `Identity a`. Further, a three-way product is isomorphic to two two-way products (i.e., `(a, b, c) ~ (a, (b, c))`):

```
-- Algebraically, T a = 1 + a*T*T
data TreeF t = Sum (Constant ()) (Product Identity (Product t t))
```

Facts 1-4 above allow us to conclude that `TreeF t` is a functor whenever `t` is a functor.

Finally, we can use "fact" 5 to conclude that `Fix TreeF (Fix TreeF) ~ Tree` is a functor.